# Is there any way to use ~/odbcinst.ini instead of /etc/odbcinst.ini?

Tags: unixodbc

Looking at 
  http://www.unixodbc.org/odbcinst.html
it looks like this is a compile-type option only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Administrator Manual (doc/AdministratorManual/index.html):

> The location of the system config files can be changed by setting
>   the ODBCSYSINI environment variable at run-time.

So this should work:

```
ODBCSYSINI=$HOME isql ...
```

Or add the line

```
export ODBCSYSINI=$HOME
```

to your .bash_profile

Note the the odbc.ini file will be looked for in your home directory  also.